# Does TortoiseSVN require any SVN servers?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I use TortoiseSVN and my projects are in my laptop. I don't use any other computers for developing my projects.

Should I install any SVN servers like VisualSVN Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need an SVN server. You may access a local repository using the file: protocol. I wouldn't advise doing this, though. Installing an HTTP or even svnserve server on your local machine is simple and doesn't consume many resources.

See http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#reponoserver

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise requires a server to connect to. You can have your local machine as that server if you want.

But I'd recommend one of two things. Either make sure you've got online backup like Mozy or Carbonite to backup your code, or use an online SVN repository like Codesion, Unfuddle, or any of a dozen others out there. They're reasonably priced for small repos and user bases, and you have the piece of mind knowing you don't have a single point of failure for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TortoiseSVN is just a SVN client, and you need a server built on your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need a subversion server to connect the client to. You could install it on your local machine. As an alternative you could use a DVCS such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) which don't require a server.